# How to prevent application shutdown on close window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF and I've got no main window (I've overwritten the OnStartup method). But when user clicks on some menu-item, I want to show the settings window.

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    new MainEnvironment();
}
```

MainEnvironment.cs:

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
Settings settings_wnd = new Settings(); // WPF window

public MainEnvironment()
{
    notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
    {
        ...

        ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]
        {
            new MenuItem("Settings", contextMenu_settingsButton_Click)
        })
    };
}

void contextMenu_settingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.settings_wnd.IsVisible)
        this.settings_wnd.Show();
    else
        this.settings_wnd.Activate();
}
```

Problem is that when user closes this window, the whole application exits too. Why? And how can I prevent that?

Thanks

Comment: I created 2 different wpf windows, when the main window starts, open the other one. I could close whichever window without causing the application terminate. So maybe you should post more code.

Comment: What is the class you are running this code in. What is `this.settings_wnd`? I sounds like what is going on is that some code is running on the close of the windows, where an exception occurs. The exception doesn't have any exception handling code, which causes the application to close. Look at the `Event Viewer` in Windows under the `Applications` tree. You should see the unhandled exception details there. #PsychicDebuging

Comment: @CliveDM My case is different. I don't have main window. In app.xaml.cs, in OnStartup method I only run `new MainEnvironment();`. And in the constructor of this class is the main code. So most of the time there is no window.

Comment: Careful with that `new MainEnvironment()` call, the garbage collector will collect it as soon as it triggers if you don't hold on to the reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The application is defaultly set to shutdown when all its windows are closed. You only need to add `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` to your App.xaml file.